# How to create properly "Add to cart" request in jMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm new in use jMeter. I need to make script which will be added particular products to cart. 
My work flow:

1. Record by BlazeMeter add to cart action.
2. Import that script to local machine
3. Add Http Request with Regular Expression Extractor inside this Http request for extract token from website.
4. Change CSRF Token variable value in Request which should add product to cart on value from first request. (extracted token)
5. Add View Tree Result.
6. Run script 
   After that everything look's good in result but on website backoffice system that cart isn't creating. 
   Additional info:
7. I have cookie manager, cache manager
8. jMeter version 2.0